# Two dimensional array read from file as argument

Tags: c++

I want to read Graph from file and start function to get max flow but i get some error when i pass this graph as function argument. What am I doing wrong?

```
int main() {
fstream file;
file.open( "macierz.txt", ios::in );

int n = 7;
int graph[n][n];

int v;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < n; j++){
        file >> v;
        graph[i][j] = v;
    }
}

cout << "Ford-Fulkerson -MATRIX- The maximum possible flow: " << fordFulkersonMatrix(graph, 0, 6) << endl;
```

function :

```
int fordFulkersonMatrix(int graph[7][7], int start, int target) {
int u, v;
int rGraph[7][7];
int parent[7];
int max_flow = 0;

for (u = 0; u < 7; u++) {
    for (v = 0; v < 7; v++)
    {
        rGraph[u][v] = graph[u][v];
    }
}
```

Error:

```
main.cpp|200|error: cannot convert 'int (*)[(((unsigned int)(((int)n) + -0x000000001)) + 1)]' to 'const int (*)[7]' for argument '1' to 'int fordFulkersonMatrix(const int (*)[7], int, int)'|
```

Comment: `int graph[n][n];` is not standard C++. Also you should prefer using containers from the C++ standard library instead of raw arrays (e.g. `std::vector` or `std::array`)

Comment: So why when i do this without read data from file everything is ok? When i initialize graph in code it works but i need reading from file.

Comment: It will compile if you use integer literal `int graph[7][7]`. But as @UnholySheep already mentioned, it is much better to use STL containers. Also try to avoid using your native language (I think Polish in this case) names for variables - it makes the code less clear for others: `plik >> v;`

Comment: Of course, i have changed names. Could you help me with this. I usually program in Java and i dont know cpp to much. I have to do this code for homework. I have to do this with matrix and Adjacency list in the second case i will use vector to represent edge. Here i have to do this on matrix.

Comment: Language syntax aside, probably you also want to look at Eigen, http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/.

Comment: I dont know if i can use some external libraries. There is no easier way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you program in Java, for sure you will like the C++ STL interfaces:

```
// or even better - use Eigen as Peter K mentioned
using MyCustomMatrix = std::vector<std::vector<int> >;

// input by const ref to prevent std::vector copy
int fordFulkersonMatrix(const MyCustomMatrix& input, int start, int target) {
    // do whatever you need to do
    // you can access your matrix elements like this:
    int elem34 = input[3][4];  // only if your matrix if big enough, of course
    // you can iterare using C++11 range loops
    for (const auto& row : input) {
        for(auto elem : row) {
            std::cout << "My elem: " << elem << std::endl;
        }
    }
    // and you can access your matrix dim information like this:
    int numRows = input.size();
    if (numRows > 0) {
        int numCols = input[0].size();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Later in the code, you can construct your matrix like that:

```
MyCustomMatrix mat;
mat.push_back(MyCustomMatrix::value_type());  // add one row
mat[0].push_back(69);  // add one elem to the first row
fordFulkersonMatrix(mat, 0, 6);
```

Expected output:

```
My elem: 69
```

This is of course very lazy solution, but maybe you don't need anything more. For some serious linear algebra operations consider using specialized libraries (like already mentioned Eigen, or boost uBLAS).